# Where are core dump files stored on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coredump

I am writing an application in objective c. I know that the .crash and .plist files (core dump files) are viewable when iPhone is synced with the Xcode Organizer in Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/(iPhone hostname). However, my application requires that I am able to view the files on the Iphone itself. Does anyone know the exact folder where these files are held?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You can't. Sandbox apps don't have permissions to read those files, sadly. If you really want this kind of functionality, I suggest filing an enhancement request at bugreporter.apple.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should be in /var/mobile/Library/Logs/

Comment: When i sync my iPhone, I can view many crash logs. However I cant find any of those inside /var/mobile/Library/Logs =/

Comment: Are they perhaps stored in the ADDataStore.sqlitedb or ADDataStore.sqlitedb-journal in that folder?

Comment: In the error console, it says the crash report is saved in /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/AppName
At the moment I don't have the device on me to check

Comment: I'm ok with using a jailbroken phone and I'm not planning on putting my app on the AppStore. I just need to check the name of the .crash files, and upload them to another server all on the iPhone itself.